# Polygon clustering

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, clustering

I have a shapefile with a number of polygon structures. The shapefile looks like this: [image].

Is there any way to cluster polygons and merge them together via Python to have something like in the following image? [image]

For now I tried quickshift from skimage.segmentation import quickshift with rasterized polygons:

```
labels = qs(backtorgb, max_dist=10000, ratio=0, convert2lab=True).astype('float')
```

watershed with threshold raster:

```
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
distance = ndi.distance_transform_edt(thresh1)
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
max_coords = peak_local_max(distance, labels=thresh1, footprint=np.ones((3, 3)))
local_maxima = np.zeros_like(thresh1, dtype=bool)
local_maxima[tuple(max_coords.T)] = True
markers = ndi.label(local_maxima)[0]


labels = watershed(-distance, markers, mask=thresh1).astype("float")
```

there are also other algorithms: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.slic but they either need primary contour or other pointers.

The best result I have now is from watershed but not exactly what I need. I also tried to play with erosion-dilation, opening-closing, the output changes but still borders of the clusters are not like I want:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried because unless you add a Python code attempt your question will be closed

Comment: Thank you, updated

Comment: Is this the only time you need to cluster them? Is there anything from preventing you doing it manually? i.e. Drawing a new polygon layer with the cluster shapes and assigning your polygons with a spatial join (being mindful of how to treat those on the borders of course).

Comment: nope. There will be different shapefiles and them should be clustered automatically

Comment: What attribute or characteristic of the polygons is the basis for the clustering?

Comment: Spatial attributes and classification for hight. Do you see these areas where no polygons? They are markers where clusters should be.